# Everything is noticably slow, restored to new 1tb ssd

Tags: hard-drive, macos, backup, ssd, hdd

Everything on my computer is noticeably slow. Before I thought that my hdd was dying (which it may have been) and (regrettably) bought a 1tb ssd to restore all of my data to. Before, my computer was so slow that I couldn't back it up, with no other apps open. Now, on the ssd (after re-installing macOS Sierra from the recovery partition), my computer is noticeably slow. It can't even run Grand Theft Auto on low settings, which it should be able to do with ease.

Before I re-installed Sierra, my computer (running on the ssd) began to gradually slow down, until all of the apps stopped responding, and disk utility said that there were problems with the ssd.
[image: when it all stopped] From there, I rebooted into the recovery partition, ran first aid on all volumes (which said that there was no problems), and re-installed Sierra.

Is there any way to make my computer running from an ssd fast, like it was for a while when running on an hdd, or even faster?

This is a '15 mid-2012 MacBook Pro (the model with a superdrive), with the ssd running from an adapter in the superdrive's place (the hdd flex cord died).

Comment: how is the CPU load

Comment: so your Battery is 6 years old, and how is it doing ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm not sure what the current CPU load is, because iStat Mini isn't showing up in Notification Center, even when I do `killall NotificationCenter`, and then relaunch it from CoreServices. Also, the battery died at ~60% capacity a couple of days ago, waiting for a new one to get shipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac computers will cut down the CPU power down to 50% if the battery is not supporting it.

In your case  been without working battery, is the reason for slow down.

PS, you do not need iStat to see CPU usage. Use the Activity Monitor

Comment: Oh huh thanks, I'll post what happens with the battery

Comment: OK, back to full speed than.

Comment: GTA SA is still laggier with a new battery (96% capacity) with the same settings as before then it was on my hdd

Comment: not surprised, you have a lots of unproven apps installed. Forget the iStat, just use Activity Monitor to see what is slowing it down.

Comment: Ok, I will in something like a week because the battery wasn't actually what I payed for, so I'll have to wait for a new one. Also, what do you mean by unproven apps? And finally, I think only Firefox and messages was open

Comment: I am not going to have this argument, but lets just name one "uBar" and looking at you menu bar (top) I can see many others (12). How do you know they do not interfere with normal operations and slow down you system.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by unproven

Comment: To establish full speed base line, close all non macos apps (all).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cZMyVi8.png found what is using all of my cpu

Comment: it won't let me kill it with `sudo killall 22104`, it says `No matching processes were found`